# Create conditional WHERE clause on joined table in Linq and EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

**Requirement:**

Show a current status of orders at this point in time. This will return all orders that are NOT yet shipped AND those orders that have been shipped TODAY.

**Data Structure:**

`OrderHeader (1) -> (many) ShippingContainerHeaders`

A copy of my code below. It originally worked with the `oh.CreatedOn` part that is now commented out. But the requirement became refined and instead needs to consider those Shipped TODAY using the specific ship date of the joined table `ShippingContainerHeader.ShipDateTimeUTC`. If any one of the ship containers for that order has a `ShipDateTimeUTC` of Today, then include it. But what I have below won't compile and gives this error:

`Error  17  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<OTIS.Domain.InventoryMgmt.ShippingContainerHeader>' and 'bool'`

```
return orderHeaderRepository
    .SearchFor(oh =>
        oh.FacilityId == intFacilityId
        && oh.OrderType == OrderHeader.OrderTypes.ShipOrder.ToString()
        && (
            oh.StatusId >= (int)OrderHeader.Statuses.Shipped && oh.ShippingContainerHeaders != null
            ? oh.ShippingContainerHeaders.Where(sh => sh.ShipDateTimeUTC >= startDateTime) //(oh.CreatedOn >= startDateTime) && (oh.CreatedOn <= endDateTime)
            : oh.Id > 0
            )
        )
```

**UPDATE**

If I change the `.Where` to `.Any`, I get this error:

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[OTIS.Domain.InventoryMgmt.ShippingContainerHeader, OTIS.Domain, Version=1.5.6054.27019, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.
```

**My Solution**

Though the accepted answer is specific in that there is no way to do what I a was trying to achieve, it does not provide an alternate solution. In the end, I had to just create a UNION query to first query all order not yet shipped and another for those that shipped, and performed a union on the two queries.

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry, added the exact error message. It won't compile.

Comment: Change `Where` to `Any`

Comment: @IvanStoev tried that as well. It compiles, but produces runtime error...see update question for details.

Comment: oh.ShippingContainerHeaders != null: EF cannot convert this to an SQL query if ShippingContainerHeaders is a navigation property - it can't possibly determine wether the property in the database should be null or an empty List. Query for oh.ShippingContainerHeaders.Any().

Comment: Add explicit parenthesis to separate the `&&` from the `!=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oh.ShippingContainerHeaders != null
            ? oh.ShippingContainerHeaders.Where(sh => sh.ShipDateTimeUTC >= startDateTime) //(oh.CreatedOn >= startDateTime) && (oh.CreatedOn <= endDateTime)
            : oh.Id > 0
```

this statment is not correct:

`oh.ShippingContainerHeaders
.Where(sh => sh.ShipDateTimeUTC >= startDateTime)` `=IEnumerable<ShippingContainerHeader>()`

`oh.Id > 0` is bool!

read  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb47kt2f.aspx) why!

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'class1' and 'class2'
>   Conversions between classes are useful when you want objects of different classes to work with the same code. However, two classes that work together cannot have mutual and redundant conversions, or no implicit conversions. The types of class1 and class2 are determined independently, and the more general type is selected as the type of the conditional expression. For more information about how types are determined, see Conditional operator cannot cast implicitly.
>   To resolve CS0173, verify that there is one and only one implicit conversion between class1 and class2, regardless of which direction the conversion is in and regardless of which class the conversion is in. For more information, see Implicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference) and Conversion Operators (C# Programming Guide).